# How to fix ssh?

Tags: ssh

SSH is no longer working and it reports no errors client side or server side

client side:
[image: client side image]

server side:
[image: server side image]

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: looks like ssh client is broken on windos side? have you tried to reinstall it ?

Comment: yeah serveral times i also removed the server ip from blacklists

Comment: Your Windows output is shouting about a config error, and pointing you toward specific files to fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, OpenSSH for windows server (and desktop) is a bit rubbish and needs the user to restart sshd using powershell with provided ps scripts every time the server is rebooted, or something that affect the service or files happens. It usually provides almost no error messages or indicators.
What I usually do is to recreate the config files, keys, and permission fixes using the provided ps scripts (should be at the installation directory). Have you tried that?

Comment: should i try PuTTy instead?